# SSRS - Creating Dynamic Columns

Tags: reporting-services

I want to develop a Dynamic SSRS Report which looks like the attached document in link below.
 Every Defect type has its own Description "Columns". The Columns in the description changes depending on the defect type. And We don't know how many columns they contain. One defect type can contain 10 columns and other can contain only 2 or nothing...any random number. I am not sure where to start and how should I proceed further. Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks...
Ankit.

http://img34.imageshack.us/img34/6848/pdpl.png

Comment: Column Grouping. BTW you are missing the attachment.

Comment: I have attached a link...Please have a look...Thank you...http://img34.imageshack.us/img34/6848/pdpl.png

Comment: Can you post your dataset. Create a matrix with column groupings will get you what you want.

Comment: I still don't have the dataset. I am looking for a start...I need some help as I don't know from where should I begin.

Comment: I found out the way I wanted to have a automatic headers in the report. I just added a Matrix in a row[X]column[X] position in the table and grouped accordingly. It done the trick for me.